# good IDE with a good profiler with GUI for C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, ide, profiler

I would like to have all the tools that i need in just one place ( aka GUI ).

There is an IDE with a profiler or an IDE that offers a plugin for a good profiler?

I'm not looking for just a profiler, i would like to have all in one place, from the editor to the profiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qtcreator http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator 
you can use it with
 [valgrind](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_valgrind_with_Qt_Creator)

Answer (score 2):

I like Netbeans more then any other IDE.
It has a build in profiler and the completion feature is imho unmatched. It offers a lot of plugins similar to eclipse but almost all of the functionality comes bundled with it.

Other than in Eclipse, the C++ support in Netbeans is developed by the core team. It feels more consistent with the overall UI.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the best thing out there:
http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/